# SyzygyPath in asmFish

Tags: engines, software, endgame, linux

Can someone point to me whereabouts in asmFish I can hardcode the SyzygyPath into the source code. I can do it in StockFish 8, however I've yet to find it in the source code of asmFish. I'll be using the Linux version.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Assembly language...

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think you should hard-core SyzygyPath because the ASM engine follows the UCI protocol. You can just send the `SyzygyPath` option to the engine.
2. If you insist to modify the assembly language (I don't recommend), goto https://github.com/tthsqe12/asm/blob/f34c20b25c2160b27efda5c5c388ff5e66636d3e/asmFish/guts/Uci.asm.

Find this:

```
.SyzygyProbeDepth:
        lea    rcx, [sz_syzygypath]
        call   CmpStringCaseless
        lea    rbx, [.SyzygyPath]
        test   eax, eax
        jnz   .CheckValue
```

Try to replace the path with `'C:\MyPath\'`.

**Note**: My recommendation is not tested, but I am sure that's the code you'll need to change.